# Is the content type hub out of fashion?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, modern-experience, administration, content-type-hub

I am creating a new intranet and in this particular tenancy there is no content type hub.

Is it still worth creating it to deploy site columns in the whole tenancy? or it is kind of surpassed?

Comment: Are you trying to create content type hub in SharePoint online or SharePoint server?

Comment: online only. Is it stiil possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Benefits and functionality of using content type is same in SP online as well. check my answer given below.

Comment: Hi @susan, does my answer given below help you in any way? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Tenant does not have a Content Type Hub in place and you are creating a new intranet, it may still be worth considering whether a Content Type Hub would be beneficial for your specific needs. Here are some factors to consider:

1. How many site collections will be part of the intranet? If there are only a few site collections, it may not be necessary to create a Content Type Hub.
2. How important is standardization of content types across the organization? If consistency is critical for your intranet, a Content Type Hub could be a useful tool.
3. Will the intranet be used for content creation and management or primarily for document sharing and collaboration? If the intranet is focused on document sharing and collaboration, a Content Type Hub may be less important.
4. Is there an existing taxonomy or information architecture in place that could be leveraged to standardize content types? If so, a Content Type Hub may not be necessary.

Overall, whether or not to create a Content Type Hub depends on your specific needs and situation. While they can be a useful tool for managing content types across an organization, they are not always necessary and may not be the best solution for every intranet deployment.

Answer (score 0):

All SharePoint Online tenants have a Content Type Hub, but it is normally managed via the Content Type Gallery in the SharePoint admin center.

This content type hub can be found at /sites/ContentTypeHub

If you have content types that need to be shared between many sites in your tenant, then the Content Type Gallery is the best way to publish and manage those content types.

[Create or customize a content type](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/create-customize-content-type)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, it is possible to use Content type hub (Content type gallery) in SharePoint online tenants.

In SharePoint Online, Content type hub site collection is automatically provisioned when you create the tenant.

You can publish, unpublish, or republish content types in the content type hub at `/sites/ContentTypeHub` or from the SharePoint admin center.

Use this link directly to access  Content type gallery in the SharePoint admin center:  [Content type gallery in the SharePoint admin center](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2185074)

Advantages and functionality of using content type hub is same in SharePoint online as well. If you want site columns or content type across multiple sites in your SharePoint online tenant, it is best practice to use the content type gallery in SharePoint online.

Check this Microsoft official documentation for more information: [Publish a content type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/publish-content-type)

Comment: Hi, does the answer above help you?